# RNN package and problems with "Predictr"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, r, predictive-modeling, rnn

I have two questions about how to use R's RNN package, specifically the trainr and predictr functions.

Let's suppose I have a time series of 4000 steps for 5 different variables.

1. How should this be passed on to the RNN, since the input has to be a 3D array? Should it be an array of dim(1, 4000, 5) or dim(4000,1,5) or something completely different?

Moreover, let's suppose I successfully train my RNN and would like to make some predictions using the predictr function.

2. Which dimension will the output have and how can it be interpreted?

Until now I have tried to input the data as 3D array (4000, 1, 5) with the following code:

```
RecNN <- trainr(TrainR, TrainI, 
  learningrate = 0.003, momentum = 0.003, hidden_dim = c(100),
  network_type = "rnn", batch_size = 50,
  numepochs = 100, sigmoid = "logistic", use_bias = TRUE)

print("--- DONE LEARNING ---")
```

And then used the predictr function with the input (250, 1, 5):

```
results1 <- predictr(RecNN, TestI, hidden = TRUE, real_output = TRUE)

List of 2
 $ : num [1:250, 1, 1:100] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ : num [1:250, 1, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What code did you try and what error did you get? It will be helpful if you post your attempt here.

Comment: I have added the code to the question now!

Comment: If there is no error and output is sensible, this should be the correct approach.

Comment: Ok, but still 1. How would be the correct way of passing the input during training? An array of dim(1, 4000, 5) or dim(4000,1,5)? And 2. I am not sure how to interpret the output, why are there two lists of different lengths?

Comment: Check this and other posts on google search: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-input-dimensions-when-training-a-LSTM-neural-network-language-model

Comment: See this code in Python: https://github.com/cadrev/lstm-flood-prediction/blob/master/lstm_flood.ipynb . It also reshapes data as you are doing: `np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))`. Hence `(4000,1,5)` seems to be correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! So do you have any idea on how the output has to be interpreted? Why 2 lists of different lengths?

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnn/rnn.pdf) gives needed dimensions (see help on `trainr` function):

Dimensions of input X need to be as:

```
dim 1: samples
dim 2: time
dim 3: variables
```

and dimensions of output Y should be:

```
dim 1: samples (must be equal to dim 1 of X)
dim 2: time (must be equal to dim 2 of X)
dim 3: variables (could be 1 or more, if a matrix, will be coerce to array)
```